# Create video from images using ffmpeg and piping

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'd like to make a video of the last 10 images in a particular folder. I am trying to do this in a single line command instead of creating a list. I was trying the following, but it errors out like below. Any suggestions?

```
echo `find ./folder1 -type f | grep .png | sort | tail -10 ;`| ffmpeg -f image2 -i - test.mp4

[image2 @ 0x21bf1c0] Could find no file with path 'pipe:' and index in the range 0-4
pipe:: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Wy do you think that `-i -` would take a list of files as input?

Answer (score 2):

`ffmpeg` expects image/video data, not a literal list of files unless you're using the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat). Adding `cat` will provide the data.

```
cat $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.png' -print | sort | tail -10) | ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i - -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```